# "list assignment index out of range" error when computing array

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

As you can see below, there is an array of arrays that saves the corners of the image. I want to use this array to calculate the length of each side.

This is my code:

```
imageDrawPoints = []
imageDrawPoints.append(imageShowConers)
imageSumPoints = [] 
i=0;
for imageDrawPoints in imageDrawPoints : 
    imageSumPoints[i] = imageDrawPoints[i] + imageDrawPoints[i+1]
    i=i+1
print imageSumPoints
```

**Error:**

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 i=0;
>         5 for imageDrawPoints in imageDrawPoints :
>   ----> 6     imageSumPoints[i] = imageDrawPoints[i] + imageDrawPoints[i+1]
>         7     i=i+1
>         8 print imageSumPoints
>
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: imageDrawPoints = []
imageDrawPoints.append(imageShowConers)
print imageDrawPoints
[array([[[ 324.50048828,  325.00543213]],

       [[ 433.49432373,  325.00195312]],
       [[ 324.49880981,  432.99136353]],
       [[ 216.50079346,  216.98078918]],

       [[ 108.50048065,  325.00384521]],

       [[   2.63793683,  325.0098877 ]],

       [[ 108.49881744,  216.99128723]],

       [[ 216.49368286,  325.01428223]],

       [[ 108.50048065,  325.00540161]],

       [[ 324.50048828,  541.00384521]]], dtype=float32)]

Comment: Welcome to [so], you should [edit] your post to include your data instead of paste in comment.

Comment: @하이둘기 **the length of each corner and corner**? Do you mean distance between two corners? Or edge length?

Comment: @Mohammed Shareef C I'd like to find the distance between the two sides.

Comment: @senjuti Don't highlight random words that are not code with code markup (like "array of arrays").

Answer (score 0):

```
"imageDrawPoints[i+1]" is the problem.
```

If you have a list with 5 items it might look like [0,1,2,3,4]

When you get to the end of your iteration your code will be looking for:

```
imageDrawPoints[4+1]
```

which doesn't exist in your array and will throw the error.

Since I don't know what your code needs to do (you need to figure that out), but you need to add some condition looking for the end of the array and doing something alternative.

Something like:

```
listExample = [0,1,2,3,4]

counter = 0
for i in listExample:

        if counter != len(listExample) -1:
        print i
        l = listExample[counter] + (listExample[counter+1])
        else:
            print "End Of Shape"

    counter+=1
```

Comment: Hello Ed Baker.So what do I need to change if I have to solve this problem?

Comment: I have added a code example, if you're satisfied please mark the question as answered